# Validate using Parsley only on form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parsley

The Parsley custom validators are being called every time a key is pressed. When you for example have a login screen, you don't want to show the user whether they have typed the correct password while they are typing. Is there any workaround using the validators?

I tried a solution with using custom errors with `addError` but this gave me the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.

Reading the documentation didn't help me much with how to use this function.

jQuery:

```
$("#password").parsley().addError(this, "password");
```

HTML:

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password"placeholder="Password">
```